# After RCA Voyager Factory Reset, It fails to connect to the internet

Tags: wi-fi, rca-voyager

My phone says it's connected to Wi-Fi, but when I push next it says it couldn'
t connect to the internet.

Comment: Could this suggestion on a similar question be useful: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/176537/12442

Comment: Is this during initial setup?

Answer (score 0):

Look up at the status bar. Does it have the Wi-Fi icon? If so, your connected. If not, finish up the setup and try going into Settings > Wifi and try again. Still no luck? Make sure your internet does not require a sign-in, and that the password is correct. Sometimes Android has little glitches like that.